# Sellers Invoice email sent again after a week for old orders in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, extensions, invoice

We are using Magento and integrate it with Webkul marketplace extension i stopped the email sent to the sellers after order placed but we have a problem now invoice email for old orders were sent to sellers again after about 5 days.

So please if you can help us to know what are the reasons of this problem?